# Import a .pem file in to a Java Keystore with valid key pair

Tags: security, x509certificate, private-key, pem

Am trying to import a .pem file in to the JKS, using below command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias nagar -file Downloads/nagardir.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

The .pem file gets imported fine but, it is not creating a key pair.

When I try to change the password using

```
keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks -alias nagar -keypasswd
```

I get an error , `Alias has no Key`

How do I import the .pem file in a proper way. I would appreciate a Windows solution.

Comment: What does `Downloads/nagardir.pem` contain?